# What's the best test coverage app in python / django

Tags: python, django, testing, code-coverage

What's the best test coverage app in python / django ?
I've found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-coverage

However I'm searching for something like simplecov(https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) in rails

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for opinions on something are not on-topic for Stack Overflow. There are several other places where they might get a better reception; you should try there instead.

Answer (score 1):

All the coverage tools you find are built on top of coverage.py (http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage).  They provide various options for integrating it with other frameworks like Django, and for configuring it.  Usually, you can do just fine by using coverage.py directly, in fact, often the other plugins add a layer of indirection that make diagnosing problems difficult. :)